# How to map an arbitrary URL in JSF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I need to be able to map a Facebook API callback to an **arbitrary URL** in my *JSF 2.1* webapp.

I'm new to JSF and as far as I can tell the only option is to create a **dummy view** at the intended *location*. I'm used to working with Spring MVC, where you map the URLs directly in controllers.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is done in JSF by returning an outcome string in an action method.

For example:

```
<h:commandButton label="submit" action="navController.verifyAnswer" />

public String verifyAnswer() {
  if(true) return "nextPage";
  else return "errorPage";
}
```

where the outcome String "nextPage" is transformed to the view ID nextPage.xhtml and errorPage to errorPage.xtml. If you return null then the next view is the same view.
More details in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavb.html#bnavc)

Comment: I was just comparing to this "Spring MVC, where you map the URLs directly in controllers" which can be done as above. Now I have reread your question, what is an arbitrary url. Can you explain little bit clear with an example probably.

Comment: An arbitrary url is **any** URL. E.g. if I want the Facebook API callback to go to http://mycoolwebsite.com/facebook then I would like to just have a "controller" entry point in JSF without having to put a dummy page at that location, such as in Spring MVC (which I'm very familiar with). Is that possible in JSF?